# Passing variable into YAML file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass a variable to a pr trigger depending on what branch I want to create a pull request with. Is it possible to pass different variables when the pipeline runs automatically. Or do I have to manually trigger the pipeline with a new variable before running it?

**My YAML snippet with the variables**
[image: **YAML SNIPPET**]

Comment: hi, just want to check whether below variables is help for you? Feel free to leave comment here if you still facing any other issue or puzzle about it:-) In addition, appreciate for [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930) if it indeed help.

Comment: Oh yes it worked thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome My pleasure to give you assistance:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the screenshot you shared in the question, seems the source of this YAML pipeline is one of your Azure Devops Repos.

But, according the doc [YAML PR trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pr-trigger):

> **YAML PR triggers** are only supported in GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud.

[image]

For Azure Devops repos source, the **YAML pipeline triggered by PR** can only be achieved by [Build policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation). If you don't specify the build policy and just use `pr` in YAML, it will not work.

---

> pass a variable to a pr trigger depending on what branch I want to
>   create a pull request with.

Why not directly to use the [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables) which can let the YAML know what branch that the pull request created with:

`System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` : The branch that is being reviewed in a pull request.

`System.PullRequest.TargetBranch`: The branch that is the target of a pull request.